# flexslider on blogger - change source

Tags: blogger, flexslider

I would like to change the source of the image/posts appearing inside the Flexslider on Blogger. 
Right now, it shows the "Most Recent Posts" but I would like to show only posts with a specific label/category. 
I tried to work on the following code, but can't figure out how to change...

```
<script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get posts feed by label use this path `/feeds/posts/default/-/labelName`

Replace `labelName` with a valid label name.

```
<script>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/labelName?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>
```